# WCF SOAP Return File Stream to Download

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, stream

i am using WCF SOAP service for my web service, i want to return a file as a stream from the web service the issue is that the file data ends up in the soap envelope which i do not want i just want the file stream to be returned, can someone please help this is what i have at the moment.

```
   [OperationContract]
   Stream GetDocument();

    public Stream GetDocument()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:/Temp/test.txt";
        try
        {

            System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
            System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            return stream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

web.config

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BasicBinding.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" 
             closeTimeout="01:01:00" 
             openTimeout="01:01:00" 
             receiveTimeout="01:01:00" 
             sendTimeout="01:01:00" 
             allowCookies="false" 
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             messageEncoding="Text" 
             textEncoding="utf-8" 
             transferMode="Streamed" 
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>

    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="BasicBinding.ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" 
              bindingNamespace="" 
              contract="IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

response

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetDocumentResponse>
         <GetDocumentResult>dGVzdCB0ZXN0IHRlc3QgdGVzdA==</GetDocumentResult>
      </GetDocumentResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

so all i want is to return the file as a stream and not in a soap envelope, can someone please help???

Comment: WCF (as you're using it) uses SOAP - you could look at perhaps using a RESTful service to return a stream.

Comment: By the way, `throw ex` is bad - you will lose the original stack trace.  Additionally, if you don't catch it in the service (for example, if you haven't implemented `IErrorHandler`), the exception will be unhandled and the service will stop.